# Is IDP(International driving permit) proof mandatory for Schengen visa application

Tags: paperwork, driving, schengen-visas, tourist-visas, applications

I have applied for a Schengen visa and within the itinerary I have mentioned that from Rome to Amalfi I will be using a rental car but I did not attach copy of my driver license or the IDP. Will this lead to rejection?

The other thing to consider is that I have mentioned in the cover letter  that I will be traveling with a group of friends, so will the visa officer understand that maybe its my friend who will will drive and approve my visa request?

Comment: I doubt that not submitting driving-related paperwork will make a material difference to the decision. The visa officer won’t infer anything that isn’t explicitly stated in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application materials will say what evidence you should submit.

I can't see any reason why they would need a copy of your driving license. Driving around Italy in a hire car is a completely normal thing to do. Having a driving license is completely normal. You don't need to prove things that are completely normal. Everybody knows you need a driving license to drive and nobody would claim they were going to drive if they didn't have one.

And, just for a moment, pretend that your application is all a big lie, you can't drive a car and you just said you were going on a road trip so that your visa application would look more realistic. Pretend that what you really want to do is live illegally in Italy. Is forgetting to include a copy of your driving license really going to be the only clue that you were lying? It seems unlikely.